# Mongoose saves a document successfully but it is not reflected in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is what the model looks like

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const popBookSchema = new Schema({
      title: String,
      url: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PopBook', popBookSchema);
```

and this is what the controller looks like

```
exports.addBook = async(req, res) => {
  const book = await Book.findOne({title: req.query.book});
  const popBook = new PopBook(book);
  console.log(book);
  console.log(popBook.url);
  await popBook.save()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('successfully saved popular book');
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
  });
  res.send(popBook);
}
```

Now the conosle.log prints the book and popbook.url and i also get the "successfully saved " message in console but there is nothing inside the database. The collection doesn't exist in the db. Now i tested it with another model and everything works fine. I just can't find the problem here.

Comment: check if popbooks collection exists in your db. Also share your db connection url (*** your domain and share)

Comment: As i said, the collection does not exist. I created another test model and tested that, it works, the test collection has a document saved in it. But the same doesn't work for popBooks. Here is the connection string mongodb://admin:*****@********:27017/books and i connect like this mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });

Comment: is there any difference between both of your schemas?

Comment: I have tested your code, it works fine. There may be a case i.e. you created PopBook in mongo cli, now if you want to connect with mongoose you have to add  new Schema({
      title: String,
      url: String
},{collection:"collectionName"}); TRY THIS

Answer (score 0):

When you create a collection in mongo cli, and you want to connect it with mongoose you have to add {collection:"collectionName"} in Schema i.e.

```
new Schema({ title: String, url: String },{collection:"collectionName"});
```

TRY THIS

Comment: I am not creating collection in mongo cli. On the contrary the collection is not created by mongoose as one would expect it to create a collection before saving a document.